# Forth as an interactive C program tester

Tags: testing, interactive, forth

I'm willing to use an interactive language to test some C code from a legacy project. I know a little Forth, but I haven't ever used it in a real world project. I'm looking at pForth right now.

Is it reasonable to use an interactive Forth interpreter to test the behavior of some function in a C program? This C code has lots of structs, pointers to structs, handles and other common structures found in C.

I suppose I'll have to write some glue code to handle the parameter passing and maybe some struct allocation in the Forth side. I want an estimate from someone with experience in this field. Is it worth it?

Comment: Surely it would make more sense to write test harnesses for your C code in a language that integrates well with C. Let's see, I'm sure I've seen one of those lying around here. Oh, yes, here it is - it's called **C.**

Comment: I want something interactive and I don't have an underlying OS. To use C, I would have to write a Little interpreter shell, which seems more trouble than using Forth or Lua. Hence The question.

Comment: pForth does appear to have support for calling C functions from within. I've not used pForth, so I don't know how capable that feature is. Is this something that will be rolled out to a larger organization? If so, you may find yourself needing to justify your decision to use pForth over using C. I have no bias myself against using Forth, if it's the right tool for the situation. I'm just all to well aware of what happens in a C/C++ shop when I mention other languages.  :)

Comment: It's just to help me test and understand huge legacy Project. I agree with you. I've tried pForth with C and it is nice, but I'd to hear from someone with experience what problems I could face.

Comment: I'm by no means a Forth expert but I've been fascinated with it for years and have done some small utility programming with it. If pForth works for you and you enjoy it, by all means use it, but I would probably use Python. It's also interactive and it integrates well with C.

Comment: There are deverão better options, but I'd like to do this on very limites hardware. No POSIX OS. Libffi probably won't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want interactive testing and are targeting embedded platforms, then Forth is definitely a good candidate. You'll always find a Forth implementation that runs on your target platform. Writing one is not even hard either if need be.

Instead of writing glue code specific to your immediate needs, go for a generic purpose Forth to C interface. I use [gforth's generic C interface](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Call_a_foreign-language_function#Forth) which is very easy to use.  For structure handling in Forth, I use an [MPE style implementation](http://forth.sourceforge.net/word/structure/) which is very flexible when it comes to interfacing with C (watch out for proper alignment though, see gforth %align / %allot / nalign).

The definition of generic purpose structure handling words takes about 20 lines of Forth code, same for single linked lists handling or hash tables.

Since you cannot use gforth (POSIX only), write an extension module for your Forth of choice that implements a similar C interface. Just make sure that your Forth and your C interface module uses the same malloc() and free() than the C code you want to test.

With such an interface, you can do everything in Forth by just defining stub words (i.e. map Forth words to C functions and structures).

Here's a sample test session where I call libc's `gettimeofday` using gforth's C interface.

```
s" structs.fs" included also structs \ load structure handling code

clear-libs
s" libc" add-lib  \ load libc.so. Not really needed for this particular library

c-library libc    \ stubs for C functions
\c #include <sys/time.h>
c-function gettimeofday gettimeofday a a -- n ( struct timeval *, struct timezone * -- int )
end-c-library

struct timeval          \ stub for struct timeval
    8 field: ->tv_sec   \ sizeof(time_t) == 8 bytes on my 64bits system
    8 field: ->tv_usec
end-struct

timeval buffer: tv

\ now call it (the 0 is for passing NULL for struct timezone *)
tv 0 gettimeofday .  \ Return value on the stack. output : 0
tv ->tv_sec @ .      \ output : 1369841953
```

Note that `tv ->tv_sec` is in fact the equivalent of `(void *)&tv + offsetof(struct timeval, tv_sec)` in C, so it gives you the address of the structure member, so you have to fetch the value with `@`. Another issue here: since I use a 64 bits Forth where the cell size is 8 bytes, storing/fetching an 8 bytes *long* is straightforward, but fetching/storing a 4 bytes *int* will require some special handling. Anyhow, Forth makes this easy: just define special purpose `int@` and `int!` words for that.

As you can see, with a good generic purpose C interface you do not need to write any glue code in C, only the Forth stubs for your C functions and structures are needed, but this is really straightforward (and most of it could be automatically generated from your C headers).

Once you're happy with your interactive tests, you can move on to automated tests:

- Copy/paste the whole input/output from your interactive test session to a file named testXYZ.log
- strip the output (keeping only the input) from your session log and write this to a file named testXYZ.fs
- To run the test, pipe testXYZ.fs to your forth interpreter, capture the output and diff it with testXYZ.log.

Since removing output from an interactive session log can be somewhat tedious, you could also start by writing the test script testXYZ.fs then run it and capture the output testXYZ.log, but I prefer starting from an interactive session log.

Et voilà !

For reference, here's the structure handling code that I used in the above example :

```
\ *****************************************************************************
\ structures handling
\ *****************************************************************************

\ Simple structure definition words. Structure instances are zero initialized.
\
\ usage :
\ struct foo
\     int: ->refCount
\     int: ->value
\ end-struct
\ struct bar
\            int: ->id
\     foo struct: ->foo
\       16 chars: ->name
\ end-struct
\
\ bar buffer: myBar
\ foo buffer: myFoo
\ 42 myBar ->id !
\ myFoo myBar ->foo !
\ myBar ->name count type
\ 1 myBar ->foo @ ->refCount +! \ accessing members of members could use a helper word

: struct ( "name" -- addr 0 ; named structure header )
    create here 0 , 0
  does>
    @ ;

\ <field-size> FIELD <field-name>
\ Given a field size on the stack, compiles a word <field-name> that adds the
\ field size to the number on the stack.

: field: ( u1 u2 "name" -- u1+u2 ; u -- u+u2 )
    over >r \ save current struct size
    : r> ?dup if
    postpone literal postpone +
    then
    postpone ;
    + \ add field size to struct size
; immediate

: end-struct ( addr u -- ; end of structure definition )
    swap ! ;

: naligned ( addr1 u -- addr2 ; aligns addr1 to alignment u )
    1- tuck + swap invert and ;

\ Typed field helpers
: int: cell naligned cell postpone field: ; immediate
: struct: >r cell naligned r> postpone field: ; immediate
: chars: >r cell naligned r> postpone field: ; immediate
\ with C style alignment
4 constant C_INT_ALIGN
8 constant C_PTR_ALIGN
4 constant C_INT_SIZE
: cint: C_INT_ALIGN naligned C_INT_SIZE postpone field: ; immediate
: cstruct: >r C_PTR_ALIGN naligned r> postpone field: ; immediate
: cchars: >r C_INT_ALIGN naligned r> postpone field: ; immediate

: buffer: ( u -- ; creates a zero-ed buffer of size u )
    create here over erase allot ;
```